get unique lines from a file
For reference, this is a follow-up on @EdMorton's answer to my previous question: make master/slave ip in different subnet
I have a file have duplicates on both first column and the second column,just need to get the lines on which the first column is unique and second column is unique.may hav several results,but it's not a problem
a d
a e
b f
b e
c f
c d

desired output:
a e
b f
c d

or
a d
b e
c f

I have tried the following code, but only get two lines output as:
a d
b f

declare -A left_ips
declare -A right_ips
results=()

while read -r line; do
    left_ip=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    right_ip=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')

    if [[ -z "${left_ips[$left_ip]}" && -z "${right_ips[$right_ip]}" ]]; then
        results+=("$line")
        left_ips[$left_ip]=1
        right_ips[$right_ip]=1
    fi

done < /tmp/tmp.txt

for result in "${results[@]}"; do
    echo "$result" 
done

issue resolved,thanks for your help,we don't need to grep lines any more.

Related: Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?

as I can't find a better way to handle this

Why should it choose a e over a d?  To me, your script has reasonably done the job requested.

it's not a problem,may be several results,but the desired output will have three lines, I only get two

Neither a in column one nor e in column two are unique. I cannot think of a plain uniqueness criteria that could make an algorithm choose a e but not a d. Your intendet result is either just one of many valid selections, or simply arbitrary.

a d/b e /c f is valid result,just need first column unique and second column unique

You might try sorting the input (sort), or randomizing it (shuf).  The output you are getting is a result of the order of the input.  You might also try automating validating the output, so you can try different input orders.

Blunt force option - generate all possible output combinations for each unique value in the first column (see my previous answer) and then read them and count unique values to find which combination(s) produce the most values from each input set. So try a b and see how many other outputs you could get, then backtrack and start instead with a e and count again, and so on.
